# WPF: update data of syncfusion chart

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I'm using syncfusion to build a chart, but my problem is that I load the window and the chart first. Then I change comboboxes on the window to set filters and afterwars I want to see the data in the chart. But I haven't found a solution to update the chart once it was created. So I just see a empty chart all the time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the reported query and we have suspected that your requirement is to “Chart’s ItemsSource update according to the filter changes in ComboBox” as per your update like “haven't found a solution to update the chart once it was created”. Dynamic update on Chart has been done by notifying its collection changes on binding property of Chart’s ItemsSource with the help of NotifyPropertyChanged as per in below code snippet

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ….

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<ChartData> data;

    public ObservableCollection<ChartData> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Here, we have prepared the demo application to change the ItemsSource of Chart based on the ComboBox’s selected items. Please find its UI as per in below code snippet

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Select the options"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="300" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxData}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <syncfusion:SfChart Margin="0,40,0,0">
        <syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <syncfusion:CategoryAxis Header="Name" />
        </syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
        <syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            <syncfusion:NumericalAxis Header="Height(in cm)" />
        </syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

        <syncfusion:ColumnSeries 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference comboBox},Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource ChartDataSourceConverter}}" 
            XBindingPath="XValue" 
            YBindingPath="YValue" />
    </syncfusion:SfChart>
```

We have achieved this by keeping the Chart data source related with the ComboBox’s SelectedItem as per in below

```
 public ViewModel()
    {
        ComboBoxData = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person
            {
                Name = "David",
                Data = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>()
                {
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "X1",YValue = 5},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "X2",YValue = 10},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "X3",YValue = 15},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "X4",YValue = 20},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "X5",YValue = 25},
                }
            },

            ……

            new Person
            {
                Name = "John",
                Data = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>()
                {
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "Z1",YValue = -10},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "Z2",YValue = -20},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "Z3",YValue = -25},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "Z4",YValue = -30},
                    new ChartData(){XValue = "Z5",YValue = -35},
                }
            },
        };
    }
```

Please have a sample in below link

Sample Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/259576/ze/DemoSample1670537327